# In Haskell, how can I freeze/thaw a mutable vector of mutable vectors in O(1)?

Tags: haskell, vector, graph

I'm using `MVector`'s from the `vector` library to represent some adjacency list for a graph. This question requires good knowledge of the `vector` package.

I want some of my graph functions to take as input a mutable graph, because they might change it. And some other functions should take as input an immutable graph because they are not meant to change it.

Until now each graph function I have is taking a mutable graph as input. This is not nice.

I like how `unsafeFreeze` from here https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.1.2/docs/Data-Vector-Generic.html allows to get an immutable version of a vector in O(1).
I believe that under the hood it really does nothing else than casting the type.

Essentially I want to be able to "unsafe" freeze frequently any complex mutable structure at zero cost, so that I can pass it to functions where an immutable argument is required. Just like in any common programming language. Despite the "unsafe" prefix, I feel this is not unsafe practice if the frozen structure is discarded right after its use as an immutable argument. Garbage collection should not happen as the mutable version is not discarded, and frozen version should point to the same memory representation as the mutable version.

What I'm having trouble with is freezing a graph seen as a mutable vector of mutable vectors. The only way I figured out so far, is to generate a new immutable version of the main vector with `unsafeFreeze` called on each mutable subvector. But that is O(n) in the length of the main vector. This is not acceptable.

To clarify, unsafe freezing the main vector alone, is not enough because  it gets me a frozen vector of mutable vectors. In theory there should be a way to freeze everything at no cost, because internal memory representation should not change at all. It should be nothing but a cast.

Is there a way I can freeze a mutable vector of mutable vectors in (very cheap) O(1) ?

I am aware that this question is just very specialized on the `vector` package. IF you have alternative package suggestions for mutable vectors I'm happy to hear them.

Please don't answer "Use immutable structures. Period.". My opinion is that graphs, immutability, and performance, often don't go well together.

Thanks,

Comment: I need to dive in the package and understand how unsafeFreeze works. But the vector code is quite a mess. Will take me some time to understand.

Comment: unsafeFreeze led me to this other package.
 http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.7.0.1/docs/src/Data.Primitive.Array.html#unsafeFreezeArray
But I don't quite understand yet this code full of sharps. Whoever downvoted, can you let me know what's wrong?

Comment: `unsafeFreezeArray#` is a compiler primitive. The `#` in it means nothing; it's just part of the name. [The implementation is here](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/blob/4898df1cc25132dc9e2599d4fa4e1bbc9423cda5/compiler/GHC/StgToCmm/Prim.hs#L406-409). It appears to do two things: rewrite the "info table" (runtime type information) and (invisibly) "cast" the pointer. An `unsafeCoerce` *might* work (very little stuff actually uses the runtime type information), but I'd just say you can't. Use a typeclassy solution to overload operations to work on both immutable and mutable graphs?

Comment: @HTNW  Yes a typeclassy solution what I did initially where I wasn't distinguishing mutable vs immutable parameters.  I found a really nice trick using injective type families: ```type family Mut s (x :: k) = (r :: k) | r -> x```. This allows me to recreate the mut pattern you see in other modern languages like Rust. Now I want all my codebase to become beautiful, but I find this vector package  quite ugly to be honest. I will try to learn how unsafe coercions work. I also thought it might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Sorry. Freezing is a one-array-at-a-time operation, period. What you might be able to do is build yourself an API that *represents* immutable structures using mutable structures. Depending on how you're using these, you may encounter some performance degradation in GC.

Another option is to use both `unsafeFreeze` and `unsafeThaw`. See for example the way `HashMap`s are constructed from lists in `unorderedContainers`. You have to be careful with this, because the type system won't be much help remembering what's going to be mutated and what won't be.